# What does "screenshot" mean in news titles?

Tags: word-meaning, proper-nouns

I recently read some articles from cityam.com and found some titles had similar patterns like "Screenshot: blahblahblah...". For example

- [Screenshot: Can social media win the anti-vax war?](https://www.cityam.com/screenshot-can-social-media-win-the-anti-vax-war/)
- [Screenshot: Is price comparison the Future of publishing?](https://www.cityam.com/screenshot-is-price-comparison-the-future-of-publishing/)
- and more ... [Search result for screenshot](https://www.cityam.com/?s=Screenshot)

I looked up the word screenshot in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/screenshot), [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/screenshot) and [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/screenshot). All of them just showed two meanings:

- as a noun: an image of what is shown on a computer screen
- as a verb: to make an image of what is shown on a computer screen so it can be copied or saved

It seems neither of the above is suitable for the use cases. Can someone help explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used as a proper noun: Screenshot. That is just the name of the column that its writer decided to use to call his column.

A [column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(periodical)) is a series of opinion articles that appear periodically in a newspaper, penned by a particular writer or a group of writers, who are called "columnists". It is customary for the editor or columnist to decide on a unique name for the column. For example, one of my favorite columns is a New York Times linguistics column called [*On Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Language), which unfortunately has discontinued.

As to why is that particular column that you are reading called Screenshot, it seems the column articles are all about taking a snap from the political/cultural environment and taking about it. So "screenshot" is arguably an apt name.